# how to skip login page if user already logged in in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi i am new to ionic framework. i am using session manager in ionic. But i want to skip login page if user is already logged in.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('grocery', ['ionic', 'grocery.controller', 'ngCordova', 'ngCordovaOauth'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $cordovaToast, $rootScope, mainItemsList, $state) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

            stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }

    });


});


$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    if (mainItemsList.isLoggedIn() != true) {
        $state.go('app.login');
    }



})


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/navigationDrawer.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

    .state('app.masterList', {
        url: "/masterList",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/masterList.html",
                controller: 'indexCtrl'
            }
        }
    })


    .state('app.login', {
        url: "/login",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.register', {
        url: "/register",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/register.html",
                controller: 'registerCtrl'
            }
        }
    })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/masterList");


});


angular.module('grocery.services', [])
    .factory('mainItemsList', function($cordovaSQLite, $cordovaToast, $cordovaPreferences) {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: function(sessionEmail) {

                $cordovaPreferences.store('email', sessionEmail).success(function(value) {
                        //$cordovaToast.showShortTop('stored');
                    })
                    .error(function(error) {
                        $cordovaToast.showShortTop("Error " + error);
                    })


                return true;
            }


        }
    })
```

I tried existing stackoverflow answers. But not working. please help me where i am wrong.

Comment: I guess using 'resolve' property in 'app.login' state will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Create a new controller and a new state called `autologin`. Make this your default state. In the `autologin` controller, check whether the user is already logged in. If he is, redirect to some page. If he is not, redirect to login.

```
  .state('app.autologin', {
    url: "/autologin",
    controller: 'autologinCtrl'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app/autologin");
```

controller:

```
angular.module('grocery').controller('autologinCtrl, function($scope, $state){
    //check if user is logged in
    if (userLoggedIn){
        state.go('app.masterList');
    } else {
        state.go('app.login');
    }
});
```

Comment: You also need to get rid of $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart'... because it will interfere

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a new `controller` for this logic,There will be a chance for flickering between the pages.So handle this by using `$urlRouterProvider`

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, mainItemsList) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/navigationDrawer.html",
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        })

    .state('app.masterList', {
            url: "/masterList",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/masterList.html",
                    controller: 'indexCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.login', {
            url: "/login",
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
                    controller: 'loginCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

    .state('app.register', {
        url: "/register",
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "templates/register.html",
                controller: 'registerCtrl'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function() {
        var logged = mainItemsList.isLoggedIn();
        // Check User logined or not
        if (logged != true) {
            return 'app.login';
        } else {
            return 'app.masterList';
        }

    });


});
```